# Committee Methods (ensemble learners) Best Model

Tags: model, classification, ensemble-learning

I have the following question and I seek your kind support:

> You are given the choice of two types of base classifiers (models) to
>   use in a (bagged) committee:
>
> - Classifier A: which is known to have an (error) variance of 40, but has been found to produce uncorrelated models under bagging
> - Classifier B: which is known to have an (error) variance of 30, but has been found to produce models with a pairwise covariance of 0.3
>     under bagging
>
> Assuming Classifiers A and B have equal error bias and a committee of
>   size 10, which Classifier would you choose and why?

Personally, I would go for Classifier B because having a variance of 0.3 is better than having uncorrelated  models.

Am I right in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. B is better for the reason you specified